# JAR file terminates unexpectedly without error

Tags: ubuntu, gnu-screen, java

I have a JAR file that I'm running in a `screen` session using `java -jar <myjarfile>` and for some reason it stops running at unexpected times. I'm redirecting both the StdErr and StdOut to different log files, but neither gives any indication as to why the JAR file is failing. It's as if I had run <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in the `screen` session. I've checked various log files but haven't come up with anything useful.

Are there any particular log files that I should check other than `/var/log/syslog` and the jar specific log files?

Answer (score 1):

There are no more log files you can check. Make sure that you catch **each** exception in your code and write a message via your logger and/or `e.printStackTrace()`.